# SwiftUI change the layout to split the view into uneven sections

Tags: swift

I have some code that can be simplified into this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("aaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaa")
        Text("bbbbbbbbbb\nbbbbbbbbbb\nbbbbbbbbbb")
    }
}
```

This will display the text split 50%:50% on the screen.

What I want is the top Text to take up 1/3rd and the second to be 2/3rds.

The views I have are images / market and others where I want to apply this. I have tried priority layout but that seems to not work (or I have done it incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GeometryReader` is a container view that defines its content as a function of its own size and coordinate space. Once you know what you have in terms of space you can assign the `height` by percentage.

```
struct SplitView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader{ geo in
            VStack{
                VStack{
                    Text("aaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaa")
                }.frame(height: geo.size.height * (1/3))
                Divider()
                VStack{
                    Text("bbbbbbbbbb\nbbbbbbbbbb\nbbbbbbbbbb")
                }.frame(height: geo.size.height * (2/3))
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the attempts I had tried I had put the GeometrReader in the wrong place (called twice). I think I was going code blind. Really appreciate the above.